# alternating row colors/numbers in Excel - VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

So I am working on a reporting tool in Access. It queries the local tables and creates a Excel document (through VBA) and makes an Excel file.

I use the following code to color alternative code and it works beautifully

```
 For a = 1 To rs.RecordCount
    With ExcelSheet          
        .Cells(a + 1, 1) = a 
        .Cells(a + 1, 1).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = IIf((a + 1) Mod 2 = 0, 2, 15)
    End With
Next
```

Note I have to do `a + 1` because a = 1 is the title row, and that is the title row.

Note: `.Cells(a + 1, 1) = 1` numbers the rows (1 , 2,  3, ...)

Note : `IIf((a + 1) Mod 2 = 0, 2, 15)`  The 2 and 15 are color codes.

Now my question is that when someone gets the Excel report they might delete a row, or do a sort operation or whatever and when they do that, it messes up the rows.

ex:

```
1  white row
2  grey row
3  white row 
4  grey row
```

if i sort them I get

```
3  white row
1  white row 
2  grey row 
4  grey row
```

which is not what I want, I want it to keep the formatting and the numbering
Anyone to accomplish this using VBA in Access?

Tech: Office 2007

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be accomplished with the `ROW()` function and some conditional formatting. The `ROW()` function returns the current row of the cell it is in, so it will change whenever cells are deleted, moved or sorted. Conditional formatting is re-applied whenever its conditions change, so moving or sorting rows would inform Excel to update the colors accordingly. The code would look as follows:

```
Dim a As Integer
Dim oneRow As Range

For a = 1 To rs.RecordCount 
    With ExcelSheet

        ''// show the row number in the first cell
        .Cells(a + 1, 1).Formula = "=ROW()"

        ''// set formatting to alternate row colors
        Set oneRow = .Cells(a + 1, 1).EntireRow
        oneRow.FormatConditions.Delete
        oneRow.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
            "=MOD(ROW()-1, 2)=0"
        oneRow.FormatConditions(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 2
        oneRow.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
            "=MOD(ROW()-1,2)=1"
        oneRow.FormatConditions(2).Interior.ColorIndex = 15

    End With
Next a
```

Comment: How do i manually enter in the row number?
What about the number column? I dont want 1, 2, 3 to 2, 3, 1 when the rows are sorted.

Comment: @edit, this was meant for someone else who commented, but deleted there comment. I will leave here for reference. I think I may have misguided you. This code is in Access, i create the document, all the formatting, the data is done through VBA on Access. Then i just call ExcelObject.save to save the file. 

If I number them from the Access DBA, thats fine but a user may open up the Excel sheet and re order the rows. Then since there is no macro in Excel, it will mess up the rows numbering

Comment: Users are not very Excel-savvy. They just want to sort and print. Not one of them know a single line of code.

Comment: I updated my code with a manually-entered title row number to match your example. This will retain its formatting even if rows are moved around, sorted, deleted, etc.

Comment: It was my deleted comment.  Sorry, I missed that you are generating an Excel sheet from Access.  This solution should work (or, alternatively, you could set up a basic template excel sheet and copy/edit that.  That way, you can use the "conditional formatting" menu in Excel, rather than having to deal with `FormatConditions`)

Comment: Ah, I just noticed that you want the row number to change as well. I'll update with an answer to that, too.

Comment: There we go. I've tried out this code on my computer and it works as expected. Good luck!

Comment: Thankyou, I just had to `ROW() - 1` as the "data" starts from row 2 (but I dont want to count the title as row one) hope that makes sense. 

THANKYOU SO MUCH.

Comment: I also had to modify some of your code as it wasnt working for me.

`     With oneRow
                .FormatConditions.Delete
                .FormatConditions.Add xlExpression, Formula1:="=MOD(ROW(),2)"
                .FormatConditions(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 15
            End With`

Comment: Wow this is so wierd, Access completely crashes on me when it gets to the second sheet (I have three sheets in my workbook)

Comment: Even better. That looks simpler than my original, too.

Comment: I think it might be because I copy about 6000 records into the Excel sheet, and maybe after each row it copies it runs the formulas? so maybe its not crashing ,just taking forever. I'll test.

Comment: It is because of that, my time to generate the report went from 25 seconds to almost 2 minutes. i think im gonna have a talk with the boss.

Comment: You can apply all of that conditional formatting in one step to improve the speed. Just create a range containing all of the rows you have added, and apply the format to that range, outside of the loop.

Comment: @masfenix: I have added my answer below your answer. This is now a much more efficient piece of code!

Comment: A quick note about the calculation issue: you can turn automatic calculation off while adding your data, and then turn it back on afterwards. See http://www.automateexcel.com/2004/10/31/excel_vba_turn_on_turn_off_calculation/

Answer (score 1):

@e.James

```
Dim rowRange As Range


ExcelSheet.Cells(1, 1).EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 4
ExcelSheet.Cells(1, 1) = "#"
Set rowRange = Range("2:2", rs.RecordCount & ":" & rs.RecordCount)
rowRange.Select
With ExcelApp.Selection
    .FormatConditions.Delete
    .FormatConditions.Add xlExpression, Formula1:="=MOD(ROW(),2)"
    .FormatConditions(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 15
End With
```

That dosnt work. It just highlights the very top row (the title row) grey.

EDIT NEVERMIND
Its supposed to be

```
Set rowRange = ExcelSheet.Range("2:2", rs.RecordCount & ":" & rs.RecordCount)
```

EDIT NUMBER 2:
Do you know how I can insert the row numbers in each row using this method?

ANSWER:

```
ExcelSheet.Cells(1, 1).EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 4
Set RowRange = Range("2:2", rs.RecordCount & ":" & rs.RecordCount)
RowRange.Columns(1).Formula = "=ROW()-1"
With RowRange
    .FormatConditions.Delete
    .FormatConditions.Add xlExpression, Formula1:="=MOD(ROW(),2)"
    .FormatConditions(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 15
End With
```

Comment: oh my god, that was so easy lol. Maybe its the end of the workday and im just missing my caffeine.

Comment: It also brought my time down from 25ish seconds to 10 - 13 seconds taking away 3 loops